# Best practices around including files in your iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, file-io

I am looking to include a PDF file in my iOS application.  What's the best place to put it?  I read about Asset Catalogs but it doesn't seem to be the place.  Are there any gotchas I should look out for?

Comment: Do you want to include them in the file that will be submitted to itunes and downloaded by the user?

Comment: Yes I am debating doing that or possibly using Parse.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on the best place to add data files in an iOS app.  Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right - an Asset Catalog can only include **Image sets, App icons, Launch images and OS X Icons** as explained in the [Asset Catalog documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html).

I'm not aware of any special containers for PDF files - therefore I would recommend to simply import the PDF files in your app bundle (e.g. just drag and drop the file within xCode). To keep it tidy you might want to create a specific PDFs group where to keep all your PDF resources.

[image]